# Анимация перехода на предыдущую активити через toolbar (Android)

Tags: java, android, анимация, activity, toolbar

Реализовал кнопку назад на toolbar, но проблема в том, что при ее нажатии предыдущая активити появляется с анимацией, как будто я открывают новую активити (появляется справа на лево). Я хочу чтобы была обратная анимация, когда перехожу на предыдущую активити. При этом, если нажимать аппаратную кнопку назад, то обратная анимация проигрывается. Каким образом это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для использования анимации на подобии с той которая выполняется при нажатии кнопки назад нужно в intent toolbar-a написать такую строку:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.comming_in, R.anim.comming_out);
```

Так же можно создать свою анимацию. Для этого нужно создать папку `res->anim` и там создать файл `trans_right_in.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0" />

</set>
```

так же нужно добавить анимацию при покидании активности `trans_right_out.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />

</set>
```

и использовать созданную анимацию можно так же как и в примере выше:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.trans_right_in,R.anim.trans_right_out);
```

Еще один из вариантов - использовать код нажатий на кнопку назад. То есть при использовании тулбара у вас будет поведение прописанное на нажатие кнопки назад:

```
this.super.onBackPressed();
```

Comment: R.anim.comming_in, R.anim.comming_out  самому создавать?

Comment: они в комплекте должны идти, но если не находит то создайте

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.